# Excel solution for a hyperlink that returns something for a param given to the link

Tags: excel, web-applications

I have a web app here:

> http://www.mihaigo.myfreewebsite.info/translator.php?param=OriginalInterbankSettlementAmount

This returns the abbreviation of a word like OriginalInterbankSettlementAmount. It returns OrglItbkSttlAm by some rules and a dictionary put in my web-app. I will give another example:

> [www.mihaigo.myfreewebsite.info/translator.php?param=CancellationReasonInformationOriginatorIdentificationOrganisationIdentificationAnyBIC](http://www.mihaigo.myfreewebsite.info/translator.php?param=CancellationReasonInformationOriginatorIdentificationOrganisationIdentificationAnyBIC)

that returns CnclRsnInfOrgnIdOrgIdAnyBIC.

The ideea is that I have an column of ~300 terms like that and I would need to make a formula or something to obtain the abbreviation from my webapp and I would like to know if there is any solution for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the code in Javascript so that I can input the ~300 terms directly here and receive the abbreviations there. [mihaigo.myfreewebsite.info/translator.php](http://mihaigo.myfreewebsite.info/translator.php)

[image]